# Не выполняются задачи Celery проект Django

Tags: python, django, celery

Когда на методе который декорирован атрибутом @task или @shared_task вызываю метод delay() то задача уходит в celery и получает статус RECEIVED и не выполняется. Использую rabbitmq-server на windows 10. Как сделать так чтобы задачи выполнялись не зависая в статусе RECEIVED?

Код файла celery.py в папке проекта:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

\# Задаем переменную окружения, содержащую название файла настроек нашего проекта.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'meleshop.settings')

app = Celery('meleshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Код в **init**.py проекта meleshop

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
# Подключение Celery
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Код из файла задач в приложении tasks.py

```
from celery import task, shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from .models import Order


@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """Задача отправки email-уведомлений при успешном оформлении заказа"""
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Заказ № {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Уважаемый {}, \n\nВаш заказ успешно создан. Номер вашего заказа - № {}.'.format(order.first_name, order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myshop.com', [order.email])
    return mail_sent


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Стектрэйс команды из консоли -> celery -A meleshop worker -l info

```
-------------- celery@DESKTOP-PSE33P1 v4.4.0 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-01-08 18:49:42
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         meleshop:0x1f1fb6a1f08
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

[tasks]
  . meleshop.celery.debug_task
  . orders.tasks.add
  . orders.tasks.order_created
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,542: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,592: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,634: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 22876 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,672: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 25932 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,695: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 18156 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:42,697: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 21264 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,713: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,757: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\cslam\pycharmprojects\meleshop\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments! leak, never use this setting in production environments!''')
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,757: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-PSE33P1 ready.
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,758: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[c4a7175f-afbc-4cdf-950f-34a8112e8792]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,758: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[e8ddae03-8fdc-4946-a031-d0a4f401c09e]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,759: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[068d35df-b73d-4804-98a8-725ffa939b6c]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,759: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[d916c151-a4b2-415b-b692-55d45acaa457]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,760: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[d19003bd-0a16-4510-ab11-c5560f371934]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,911: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[976dbf38-16e6-4515-9943-8d4f7cfcf502]
[2020-01-08 18:49:43,912: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[735c541a-769a-497a-ad69-4f36e1b90818]
[2020-01-08 18:49:44,193: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 17140 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:44,196: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 25276 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:45,046: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[c908ffb0-361c-42bb-94e0-e08b360a913b]
[2020-01-08 18:49:45,348: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 2316 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:45,857: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[7c93464f-7056-44e4-a3a4-05729b3e284f]
[2020-01-08 18:49:46,134: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 18632 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:46,663: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[f5bddc97-2416-422c-8fb5-67f37ea06af5]
[2020-01-08 18:49:46,924: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 8372 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:47,484: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.add[ac68d9b1-b597-46a0-be21-27934345b468] 
[2020-01-08 18:49:47,760: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 8332 calling self.run()

[2020-01-08 18:49:48,291: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.add[2dbc1b50-b588-465d-b5df-5b7d0aa853c0]

[2020-01-08 18:49:48,550: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 17856 calling self.run()

[2020-01-08 18:49:49,106: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: meleshop.celery.debug_task[0561975a-9aae-45da-89e5-bab890111072]
[2020-01-08 18:49:49,373: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 1608 calling self.run()
[2020-01-08 18:49:49,913: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.add[3ed3eb03-3891-4fde-a550-4c84b9081f85]
[2020-01-08 18:49:50,178: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 3796 calling self.run()
```

Comment: Мне интересно, этот вопрос как-то решился? А то сам с таким столкнулся и понять не могу в чем же проблема Т_Т

Answer (score 1):

Я пока тоже только учусь разбираться с celery, в связке с RabbitMQ. Мне в данном случае помогло, при запуске celery прописать в терминале так:

**celery -A myshop worker -l info --pool=solo**

P.S. столкнулся с этой проблемой так же при изучении книги, из которой ваш код.